# C++ - Using std::count() with abstract data types?

Tags: c++, stl, count, operator-overloading

My code is using std::count() on a list of an abstract data type that i have defined. (Sommet or Edge in english). But it doesn't work, although i've overloaded the < and == operators like this :

```
bool operator< (const Sommet &left, const Sommet &right)
{
  if(left.m_id_sommet < right.m_id_sommet)
    return true;

  return false;
}

bool operator== (const Sommet &left, const Sommet &right)
{
  if(left.m_id_sommet == right.m_id_sommet)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

Just notice that this worked using std::sort() and std::unique().

The errors are:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In function 'typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::difference_type std::count(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Tp&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Sommet*, std::vector<Sommet, std::allocator<Sommet> > >, _Tp = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Sommet*, std::vector<Sommet, std::allocator<Sommet> > >]':
Graphe.cpp:43:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_algo.h:422: error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Sommet*, _Container = std::vector<Sommet, std::allocator<Sommet> >]() == __value'
Sommet.h:7: note: candidates are: bool operator==(const Sommet&, const Sommet&)
```

Thanks !

**EDIT**

This is how i used std::count() :

```
 for(vector<Sommet>::iterator iter = m_sommets.begin();
      iter != s_iter_end; iter++)
  {
    iter->SetNbSuccesseurs(count(m_sommets.begin(), m_sommets.end(), iter));
  }
```

Comment: Keep in mind you can just do `return left.m_id_sommet < right.m_id_sommet;` rather than the if.

Comment: Agreed with GMan, doing the spurious `if` is a poor coding practice.

Comment: Indeed, will do it next time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are passing in an iterator as the last parameter to `std::count` whereas you need to pass in a value (by const reference).

Post edit: it looks like I was correct, you are passing `iter` which is an iterator. You need to dereference it first. Try passing `*iter` instead.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to pass to `count` is a value, not an iterator:

```
iter->SetNbSuccesseurs(count(m_sommets.begin(), m_sommets.end(), *iter));
```